# Configuring MySQL Master/Slave Replication

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I am at a loss to understand why I try configuring replication master to slave it simply does not work. I have followed along with several how-to's on the Internet. However, each one of these results in an error starting the slave on server2. Here is an excerpt of the log where I try starting the replication on server2 (slave).

```
131113 13:51:10 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
131113 13:51:10 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
131113 13:51:10 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131113 13:51:10 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131113 13:51:10 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131113 13:51:10 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
131113 13:51:10 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
131113 13:51:10 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131113 13:51:10 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131113 13:51:10 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
131113 13:51:10  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
131113 13:51:11 InnoDB: 5.5.34 started; log sequence number 48943768
131113 13:51:11 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
131113 13:51:11 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
131113 13:51:11 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Missing system table mysql.proxies_priv; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
131113 13:51:11 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--relay-log=mysqld-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_current' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history_long' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_consumers' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_instruments' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_timers' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'performance_timers' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'threads' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'mutex_instances' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'rwlock_instances' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'cond_instances' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_instances' has the wrong structure
131113 13:51:11 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
131113 13:51:11 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.34'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
131113 13:51:11 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'mysql-bin.000055' at position 16706386, relay log './mysqld-relay-bin.000043' position: 16677244
131113 13:51:11 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master 'slave_user@x.x.x.x:3306',replication started in log 'mysql-bin.000055' at position 16706386
140110 12:07:45 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown
```

I hope one of you can help me understand how to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: The error says "please run mysql_upgrade" -- see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-upgrade.html

Comment: Ok I will give that a go and report back, Thank you Bill.

Comment: Replication on the slave appears to have broken because these two servers be far out of sync so trying to set up replication between the two again. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, we had to restore the master and slave DBs. Upgrading was not an option because of policy/management decision.